# How to refactor a large number of array keys to object properties in a few lines of code?

Tags: php, refactoring

I have code that looks like this (full code has 47 lines):

```php
$this->outline->value         = $row['value'];
$this->outline->some_value    = $row['some_value'];
$this->outline->specs         = $row['specs'];
$this->outline->second_marker = $row['second_marker'];
$this->outline->holes         = $row['holes'];
```

How can I make this smaller while maintaining same functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $this->outline->{$key} = $value;
}
```

Comment: @Dennis: If you do this frequently, make this a method of `outline` so `$this->outline->setProps($row);` or a method in the class `$this` is referring to `setObjProps($this->outline, $row);`